# How to delete image file in directory while adding a new one using php?

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, delete-file

I'm implementing a php function for my website wherein whenever I add an image, it will replace the older one by deleting it from the directory. After deletion the new image will now be saved in the directory. Here are the important codes I used in uploading and deleting. I have problems in deleting. I've enclosed that deletion function in comments. Uploading is working fine, please help. I cannot figure out how to implement this.

```
$TARGET_PATH = "../images/banner/";

$image = $_FILES['banner'];
$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH)){

  // $sqldel = "select filename from banners where id='1'";
  // $resultdel = mysql_query($sqldel) or die ("Could not access DB.");
  // 
  // while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultdel)){
  // $target = "../images/banner" . $row['filename'];
  // unlink($target);
  // }

  $sql = "update banners set filename = '{$image['name']}' where id='1'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Image Insert Failed!");
  exit;
}
```

**Note:**

I have a directory named "home" and there are two folders named "php" and "images" wherein inside the images folder, another folder is located named "banner". All the images I want to be uploaded and deleted/replaced are in the banner folder. This php file named "banner.php" is located in the php folder. My database connection are fine so I didn't include it in the code above. Please help, I'm still a beginner willing to learn from other's advice. Database is also created without any problems and is connected properly. As I've said earlier, my uploading works fine, I'm bothered on how to implement the deletion/replacing part.

Another thing, I have a database named "database" with a table named "banners" with two columns "id" and "filename".

Comment: Do you get any errors? What are the permissions of the file to be deleted?

Comment: I don't get any errors but the expected deletion of the file that I want to replace is not deleted.

Comment: I think there is a '/' missing after "banner" in your delete `$target`.

Comment: case solved, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The code above is missing a '/' after banner where you set  $target